# Mobile testing (Test plans)

Tags: android, iphone, testing, mobile

I am new to mobile testing.I would like to test social network apps in mobile.

Anyone please suggest me good tutorials about mobile testing and also how to write test plans for social network apps.

Especially for andriod and iphone mobile devices.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Robotium http://code.google.com/p/robotium/ of Robolectric http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/

Also you can try Android Testing Framework http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html

Hope, It help you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a few useful MindMaps on Mobile Testing over at Ministry of Testing

One on generic Mobile Testing - http://www.ministryoftesting.com/2012/06/getting-started-with-mobile-testing-a-mindmap/
One on Android - http://www.ministryoftesting.com/2012/09/android-testing-mindmap/

There are more on the website.

These provide good starting points to what you should be thinking about when it comes to mobile testing.